# mysql column data display, fetching all fields of a column and displaying it as a link

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have this code to get all fields of the column "username".

what i am trying to do is, i want to display each user in a separate line and make it a link which only consists of each respective username.

For example i have the usernames MIKE and TOM in the column "username" of my database, then i want to display MIKE as a link with href="/MIKE" and TOM as a link with href="/TOM".
the amount of usernames is varying so i need to output them all.

```
    <a href="/<?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($SQL); while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['username'] . "<BR>";

}?>"><?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($SQL); while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['username'] . "<BR>";

} ?></a>
```

The way i did it here, is just taking all the names together and it outputs one link with all the names in it.

So i am wondering how i can separate each username and give it its own link?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It's OK to undertake some research for yourself. There's not at tutorial on PHP and MySQL in the world that doesn't cover this.

Comment: well could you tell me the name of this process please? i am new to php and just starting to understand it a bit. i searched alot on hrere but it seems i dunno what exactly i have to look for.

Comment: Well I'd start with 'php mysql tutorial'

Comment: Thats what i did and what i am doing right now, your arrogant comments don't help at all, might aswell write lorem ipsum instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this -

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $SQL); 
while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
 <a href="/<?php echo $db_field['username'];?>"><?php echo $db_field['username'];?></a><br/>
<?php
}
```

`mysql` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Not promoting deprecated extensions. Just to show the procedure.

Comment: great that works! thanks alot! so mysql is deprecated, can i just replace all the mysql handles with mysqli?

Comment: Updated the answer with `mysqli` extension.